# Non conjugate points on a Riemannian manifold with two connecting minimizing geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We know that for a point $q$ in the cut locus of a point $p$ in a complete Riemannian manifold there are two possibilities: the point $q$ is conjugate to $p$ or they are connected by (at least) two minimizing geodesics.

I have been told that there is an example of two conjugate points with a unique minimizing geodesic, and, conversely, of two non conjugate points connected by two minimizing geodesics.

Can someone provide me some hints about the latter? I suspect that something on the torus can help me, but I can't say anything precise.

Comment: The flat torus (or even just a cylinder) is a good place to look, since the curvature is zero. Think about what $R=0$ implies about Jacobi fields vanishing at the endpoints of a geodesic.

Comment: Of course! Since $R=0$ the Jacobi equation implies that $J$ is "affine", so if it vanishes in two points then it is constant $0$. Right?

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607191/example-for-conjugate-points-with-only-one-connecting-geodesic?rq=1