# Example where cut locus is not the separating set

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

For a Riemannian manifold $M$ the cut locus of any point $p$, denoted by $\mathrm{Cu}(p)$, consists of all points $q\in M$ such that if there exists a distance minimal geodesic joining $p$ to $q$, then any extension of it beyond $q$ is not minimal. For example, the cut locus of any point in a sphere will be the corresponding antipodal point.

The separating set of a point $p$, denoted by $\mathrm{Se}(p)$, is the collection of all points $q$ such that there exists at least two minimal geodesic joining $p$ to $q$.

By *distance minimal*, I mean the length of the geodesic is same as the distance between the points.

A [theorem](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01238473.pdf)(see Lemma 2) of Wolter says that the closure of the set $\mathrm{Se}(p)$ is the cut locus $\mathrm{Cu}(p)$.

---

**My question:** What are some examples where $\mathrm{Se}(p) \subsetneq \mathrm{Cu}(p)$. In most of the classical examples both of the sets are same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example for conjugate points with only one connecting geodesic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607191/example-for-conjugate-points-with-only-one-connecting-geodesic)

Comment: It seems the example in the answer there describe such an example. But I am not very convinced (I did not check the paper).

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry, I was having some issue so could not see the comment. I checked the paper but I am trying to follow this. I also feel the same that it should work as an example. Thanks for sharing this.